# How to filter streams values?

Tags: python, stream, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
print(yt.streams)
```

I am using pytube to download videos, but running the code I get a stream object similar to this:

```
[<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="12fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">, <Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">]
```

How can I filter only 720p resolution or a specific fps?

Comment: https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html#filtering-streams

Comment: https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.query.StreamQuery.filter

Comment: I have done it in my notebook, including merging hi-res video with audio: https://github.com/JNYH/pytube/blob/master/pytube_sample_code.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
yt.streams.filter(res="720p").first().download()    #default .filter(progressive=True)
print("Title: ", yt.title)
print("Author: ", yt.author)
```

Output:

```
Title:  YouTube Rewind 2019: For the Record | #YouTubeRewind
Author:  YouTube
```

The downloaded mp4 file size is about 94MB.
Note that only progressive stream (progressive="True") videos contains both audio/video. Adaptive stream contains audio only or video only, but can be subsequently merged. To see all streams available, try this:

```
for e in yt.streams:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="12fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="137" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.640028" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="248" mime_type="video/webm" res="1080p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="399" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.08M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="136" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401f" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="247" mime_type="video/webm" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="398" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.05M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="135" mime_type="video/mp4" res="480p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="244" mime_type="video/webm" res="480p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="397" mime_type="video/mp4" res="480p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.04M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="134" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="243" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="396" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.01M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="133" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.4d4015" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="242" mime_type="video/webm" res="240p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="395" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="160" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.4d400c" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="278" mime_type="video/webm" res="144p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="394" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="139" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="48kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.5" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
```